# Outlook 2010 Standard Saving outlook msg to Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, outlook

We have a custom Outlook add-in that takes a MailItem and does MailItem.SaveAs(filepath) to save files to SharePoint document library. Once saved to the document library the event receiver in SharePoint would read the msg file and copy the from/to, subject, sent/received date etc. to the library columns for Views to display them.

This used to work in our Outlook 2007 Professional Plus. When we moved to Outlook 2010 Standard the columns do not get updated by the eventreceiver anymore.

I tried this using a 2010 Professional Plus and seems to be working in that edition.

My question is if there is any way to get this working on a 2010 Standard edition ?

Comment: Could you provide us with more information, please? Is it off the shelf 3rd party add on? If yes, could you tell us the vendor? If its developed in house, could you give us code snippet that takes care of the save-to-sharepoint operation so that we can see what could cause the issue?

Comment: This is an in house developed code to save emails from outlook to sharepoint.

MailItem mi = (MailItem)Application.Explorer.Selection[i];
mi.SaveAs(filepath);

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late reply, had a very busy weekend.

I'm going to have to check how this code behaves with new versions of Outlook but I suspect that using MailItem SaveAs method and just pointing to library URL is not the right way around - I think you should go with Client Side Object Model for the addon (if it's possible) and that should take care of uploading file to the library along with any metadata you want it to save rather than depending on metadata extraction from uploaded file in the event receiver :)

Comment: Hi Cthulhubutt,

That doesn't help. It worked with Outlook 2007, so I am to find out what changed in my Outlook 2010, that it stopped, and what would fix it.

I understand adding more libraries will be another way getting around it, trying find a solution to our existing setup really. If Office 2010 changed by that much, we will consider other solutions.

Comment: Sorry to hear that but looking at how you are accessing SharePoint and saving file - I can't tell whether SharePoint 2007 just allows you to do so but with 2010 you're better of starting with a clean slate and doing it right :)

Comment: Thanks for helping mate. We have logged a call with Microsoft looking for an answer as to why this is not behaving the way expected. If no other solution exists, we will have to replace our customisation codes with the Client Model libraries. Much appreciate your assistance :)